# Is there a way to recognize at least one word in the input?

Tags: python

For example

```
    userDay = input("How was you day? ")
```

The user input "My day was good"
and then the program recognizes that the user said "good", and then chooses the correct response for "good".

Sorry if you don't understand, its hard to explain.

Comment: `if userDay has 'good'` then `print('good')`

Comment: This approach will probably fail for `not bad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if a substring is in a string:

```
userDay = input("How was you day? ")

if 'good' in userDay:
    print('good')
```

or you can use:

```
if userDay.find('good') == 1:
    print('good')
```

Comment: This does not match what was asked ("a *word* in input"), as it will also return `True` if "good" is inside a longer word.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and quick way would be split the response into words using **response.split()** and then check each word if it equal to **good**

This way you can avoid searching for **‘ good’** or **‘ good ‘** or **’good ‘** (good word can be starting word, ending word or somewhere in the line)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using python's built-in lexical analysis tool, [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html). It is very useful as it contains functionality that makes it easy to write a (simple) lexical analyzer.

So in your case you can do something like this:

```
import shlex
user_input = 'My day was good'
li = shlex.split(user_input)
print 'Your day was good' if 'good' in li else 'Your day was bad'
```

The `print`s here are for demonstrating purposes only.  You have to substitute them with your code that will choose the correct response for "good".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
response = input("How was you day? ")
if response == 'good':
    # do something
```

Or if you're just looking for `'good'` in the response somewhere:

```
response = input("How was you day? ")
if 'good' in response.lower():
    # do something
```